# Georeferencing window won't open QGIS 2.4

Tags: gdal, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, georeferencing

I had the georeferencer window open in QGIS 2.4 while project was running, I accidentally closed the Qgs document with the georeferencing window open (worked absolutely fine till then). When I opened QGIS again and clicked the georeferencing plugin, the window doesn't open.

I tried closing and opening the Qgs doc, deleting temp files, opening QGIS 2.2, restarting computer, but the problem persists. I don't see any error logs in QGIS when I try to open the window.

Any help or possible error checklist is welcomed.

**Update**
I've tried a quick re-install of QGIS 2.4, still no luck. looks like a complete purge is needed.

**Update 2**
I created a new user on my computer, it already has QGIS installed, and the georeferencer plugin works fine.

Comment: Do you have both QGIS 2.2 and 2.4 installed? Do you use windows? Using QGIS 2.4 and OpenSUSE 13.1 I cant reproduce described issue.

Comment: Yes, 2.2 and 2.4, Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: Did you try to delete your QGIS user directory? If there is no specific reason for using both vesions, I would suggest to uninstall 2.2 and reinstall 2.4.

Comment: When I installed 2.4, I noticed several features didn't work as well as 2.2, so I kept it. Like I said, there was no issue with the georeferencer, it worked perfectly in both versions even when both were active

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem. This should solve the bug (QGIS 2.6 under Windows):

- close QGIS
- using regedit.exe, search for "Plugin-GeoReferencer". This should point to a folder under \HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\QGIS\QGIS2\Plugins
- (optional: export a .reg version of the folder for back-up)
- *delete* the folder "Plugin-Georeferencer"
- restart QGIS. Georeferencer window should now open

Comment: I had the same problem, solved with the Regedit trick, answer n. 3!
Thanks!
Carlo

Comment: Please do not use the area reserved for direct answers to the question to make comments.  The way to say thanks here is to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

If it's in docked mode it might just be hidden

[image]

Comment: It's not docked nor hidden. The only thing that seems to happen is when I click the plugin, it cancels the active window (blue rectangle). 
Worth mentioning also clicking on the georeferncer button in the Raster toolbar doesn't work.